# How to print struct's []byte member a string

Tags: go, printing, byte

I have following structure:

```
type foo struct {
   number int
   data []byte
}
```

And I want to print an object from the structure in a "pretty" way. What I do:

```
obj := foo{
    number: 1,
    data: []byte("json"),
}
fmt.Printf("Obj: %+v", obj)
```

What I get:

```
Obj: {number:1 data:[106 115 111 110]}
```

What I want:

```
Obj: {number:1 data:"json"}
```

Can I do that without implementing Stringer or using reflection?

Comment: `fmt.Printf("Obj: %q", obj)` will print `Obj: {'\x01' "json"}`.

Answer (score 1):

*(Disclaimer: I think just using %q for debug printing is better, but it depends on your needs. I'm adding this alternative just because the [GoStringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#GoStringer) interface is an interesting trick).*

Another way beyond %q is to wrap []byte with a type that implements the GoStringer interface, that will get called for formatting `%#v`. Let's say we have:

```
type PrintableBuffer []byte

func (b PrintableBuffer) GoString() string {
    return string(b)
}
```

Now we define the struct:

```
type foo struct {
    number int
    Data   PrintableBuffer
}
```

(for this trick to work you need the member to be public :/ )

And then:

```
func main() {
    obj := foo{
        number: 1,
        Data:   PrintableBuffer("json"),
    }
    fmt.Printf("Obj: %#v", obj)
}
```

Will print out:

```
Obj: main.foo{number:1, Data:json}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably implementing `Stringer` is better, but here is an example of implementing (slightly) `fmt`'s `Formatter` interface:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type foo struct {
    number int
    data   []byte
}

func (x foo) Format(f fmt.State, c rune) {
    var s string
    switch c {
    case 's', 'v':
        if f.Flag('+') {
            s = fmt.Sprintf("{number:%d data:%q}", x.number, x.data)
        } else {
            s = fmt.Sprintf("{%d %q}", x.number, x.data)
        }
    default:
        s = "(bad formatting verb)"
    }
    f.Write([]byte(s))
}

func main() {
    o1 := foo{number: 1, data: []byte("json")}
    o2 := foo{number: 1, data: []byte("\001with\u2038unicode")}
    o3 := foo{number: 42, data: nil}
    fmt.Printf("o1: %+v\n", o1)
    fmt.Printf("o2: %v\n", o2)
    fmt.Printf("o3: %#v\n", o3)
}
```

Object `o3` is here to show how much is missing: handling nil well, handling other formatting verbs and flags, and so on.  (I haven't touched on width and precision!)

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/eWXRp8OxN9v)